# ControllerActionInvoker logging passwords as arguments in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My application is logging arguments to every action method call, which is okay except for the `Login()` method where it logs the username and password. Is there a way to exclude this?

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
  Executing action method Service.Auth.Api.Controllers.AuthController.Login (Service.Auth.Api) with arguments (USERNAME, PASSWORD) - ModelState is Valid
```

Comment: Consider using a model class instead of separate arguments. That way, only the model class instance will be logged.

Comment: That works well. Thank you for the suggestion. If you post as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a view model object instead of passing individual parameters. That way, the instance of your view model will be logged by the `ControllerActionInvoker` which would not expose the user information by default:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Username
    { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password
    { get; set; }
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // …
    }
}
```

This also allows you to use validation attributes and validate the model state at the beginning of your controller action.